# Powershell script not outputting second Where-Object

Tags: powershell

When the script is executed it gives the below, and while it gives the first Where-Object {$_.Name -like "$LDDCSRV"} correctly, it does not give the second one correctly and just prints what's listed and not the referenced variable. Any suggestions? I'm not sure where its failing.

---

Script

```
# Discovery Cluster Services

# Counter
$C = 0


$LDDCSRV = (Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster "HV-CL01" -Name "Cluster Group" | Get-ClusterResource)
# Counter
$C = 0
$F = $LDDCSRV.Count

# Start JSON
Write-Host "{"
Write-Host " `"data`":["

# For each server in $LDDCSRV
Foreach ($LDDCSRV in $LDDCSRV)
   {
    # Counter to not print comma after last object
    $C++
    Write-Host "   {"
    
    $LDDServices = (Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster "HV-CL01" -Name "Cluster Group" | Get-ClusterResource) | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "$LDDCSRV"}
    $LDDServiceState = (Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster "HV-CL01" -Name "Cluster Group" | Get-ClusterResource) | Where-Object {$_.State -like "$LDDCSRV"}
    
    if ($LDDServices -ne "") 
        { Write-Host "     ""{#CLSRV}"": ""$LDDServices""" }
        { Write-Host "     ""{#SSTATE}"": ""$LDDServiceState""" }
    
    if ($C -lt $F) { Write-Host "   }," }
    else { Write-Host "   }" }

    }
    Write-Host " ]"
    Write-Host "}"
    
    # Counter
    $C = 0
    
    
    $LDDCSRV = (Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster "HV-CL01" -Name "Cluster Group" | Get-ClusterResource)
    # Counter
    $C = 0
    $F = $LDDCSRV.Count
    
    # Start JSON
    Write-Host "{"
    Write-Host " `"data`":["
    
    # For each server in $LDDCSRV
    Foreach ($LDDCSRV in $LDDCSRV)
       {
        # Counter to not print comma after last object
        $C++
        Write-Host "   {"
        
        $LDDServices = (Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster "HV-CL01" -Name "Cluster Group" | Get-ClusterResource) | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "$LDDCSRV"}
        $LDDServiceState = (Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster "HV-CL01" -Name "Cluster Group" | Get-ClusterResource) | Where-Object {$_.State -like "$LDDCSRV"}
        
        if ($LDDServices -ne "") 
            { Write-Host "     ""{#CLSRV}"": ""$LDDServices""" }
            { Write-Host "     ""{#SSTATE}"": ""$LDDServiceState""" }
        
        if ($C -lt $F) { Write-Host "   }," }
        else { Write-Host "   }" }
    
        }
        Write-Host " ]"
        Write-Host "}"
```

---

Output

```
{
     "data":[
       {
         "{#CLSRV}": "Cloud Witness"
     Write-Output "     ""{#SSTATE}"": ""$LDDServiceState"""
       },
       {
         "{#CLSRV}": "Cluster IP Address"
     Write-Output "     ""{#SSTATE}"": ""$LDDServiceState"""
       },
       {
         "{#CLSRV}": "Cluster Name"
     Write-Output "     ""{#SSTATE}"": ""$LDDServiceState"""
       },
       {
         "{#CLSRV}": "Health"
     Write-Output "     ""{#SSTATE}"": ""$LDDServiceState"""
       },
       {
         "{#CLSRV}": "SDDC Management"
     Write-Output "     ""{#SSTATE}"": ""$LDDServiceState""" 
       },
       {
         "{#CLSRV}": "Storage Qos Resource"
     Write-Output "     ""{#SSTATE}"": ""$LDDServiceState"""
       },
       {
         "{#CLSRV}": "Virtual Machine Cluster WMI"
     Write-Output "     ""{#SSTATE}"": ""$LDDServiceState"""
       }
     ]
    }
```

Expected output

```
{
     "data":[
       {
         "{#CLSRV}": "Cloud Witness"
         ""{#SSTATE}"": ""Online"""
       },
       {
         "{#CLSRV}": "Cluster IP Address"
         ""{#SSTATE}"": ""Online"""
       },
       {
         "{#CLSRV}": "Cluster Name"
         ""{#SSTATE}"": ""Online"""
       },
       {
         "{#CLSRV}": "Health"
         ""{#SSTATE}"": ""Online"""
       },
       {
         "{#CLSRV}": "SDDC Management"
         ""{#SSTATE}"": ""Online""" 
       },
       {
         "{#CLSRV}": "Storage Qos Resource"
         ""{#SSTATE}"": ""Online"""
       },
       {
         "{#CLSRV}": "Virtual Machine Cluster WMI"
         ""{#SSTATE}"": ""Online"""
       }
     ]
    }
```

---

Data being parsed,

```
Name                        State  OwnerGroup    ResourceType
----                        -----  ----------    ------------
Cloud Witness               Online Cluster Group Cloud Witness
Cluster IP Address          Online Cluster Group IP Address
Cluster Name                Online Cluster Group Network Name
Health                      Online Cluster Group Health Service
SDDC Management             Online Cluster Group SDDC Management
Storage Qos Resource        Online Cluster Group Storage QoS Policy Manager
Virtual Machine Cluster WMI Online Cluster Group Virtual Machine Cluster WMI
```

Comment: You should construct a psobject first and then convert it to json with the built-in cmdlet ConvertTo-Json

Comment: Please, add also the expected output to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *suspect* its bc of this line

```
Foreach ($LDDCSRV in $LDDCSRV)
```

You want a unique variable identifier for the current iteration object vs. the set to be iterated over - so you and the interpreter can know which object you are referring to when you are inside the loop. Otherwise you are crossing your fingers and hoping powershell interprets everything correctly only from the scope of the control statements (which it seems to not be doing)

Consider the following ultra-simple example, where I make 4 basic objects, put them in an array, and then iterate over them using identically named variables in the foreach loop

```
 $alf = [PSCustomObject]@{
     name = "alf"; occupation = "astronaut"
 }
 $bob = [PSCustomObject]@{
     name = "bob"; occupation = "builder"
 }
 $charles = [PSCustomObject]@{
     name = "charles"; occupation = "cheesemonger"
 } 
 $david = [PSCustomObject]@{
     name = "david"; occupation = "drugdealer"
 } 
 $object = @($alf, $bob, $charles, $david)

 foreach ($object in $object)
 {
     $test = $object | Where-Object { $_.name -like "charles" }
     Write-Host ("Filter result count: " + $test.Count)
     Write-Host($test)
 } 
 Write-Host($object)
```

It yields the following output

```
 Filter result count: 0

 Filter result count: 0

 Filter result count: 1
 @{name=charles; occupation=cheesemonger}
 Filter result count: 0

 @{name=david; occupation=drugdealer}
```

Because both the set and the iterated object are named "$object", the where-object comparison is only actually filtering a "group" consisting of a single object each time. It *seems* to work because inevitably the iterated object will eventually be the one that matches the condition, but see that when the loop is completed, "$object" is now pointing only to the final object that was iterated over (good ol' David the drugdealer) as the "$object" reference was being over-written with each loop.

This example demonstrates the potential problem with that more clearly, especially when comparing against some condition or property of $object

```
$alf     = "alf"  
$bob     = "bob"  
$charles = "charles"  
$david   = "david" 

$object = @($alf, $bob, $charles, $david) 

foreach ($object in $object)
{
    $test = $object | Where-Object { $_ -like $object }
    Write-Host ("Filter result count: " + $test.Count)
    Write-Host($test)
} 
Write-Host($object)
```

Outputs

```
Filter result count: 1
alf
Filter result count: 1
bob
Filter result count: 1
charles
Filter result count: 1
david
david
```

It finds a match every time bc $object is changing what it points to every time. These are obviously very contrived examples that don't reflect the full scope of what is happening in your situation, but they should at least make clear the potential for confusion/havoc with this approach, esp. when applying it to more complex objects and groups.

I would start by refactoring with something along the lines of

```
 Foreach ($Server in $ServerGroup)
```

or whatever makes the most sense for your use case, and seeing if that doesn't lead to some more expected behavior

Somewhat tangential but I feel like the "Where-Object" cmdlet was given a very non-intuitive name. Semantically, it implies evaluating a single object, but that's not what its used for at all. It is used to filter a *group* of objects, returning only those objects from the group that match the given condition. So typically you don't need to use it from within a foreach loop, or use a foreach loop at all, bc the "Where-Object" cmdlet is basically doing that in the background when its called. But because of powershell's ultra flexible type inference and "everything-is-a-set-even-if-its-just-a-set-of-one" philosophy, its VERY easy to use that command incorrectly without ever getting so much as a warning.

```
 $d = @('a','b','c')
 $d -like $d
```

The above code yields nothing. It just silently accepts the command and returns no value (not true/false, not even null), giving no warning. Because what its actually doing is sequentially testing that like comparison to every item in the list, and returning only those that fit - exactly like where-object does!

```
$d = @('a','b','c')
$d -like 'c'

'c'
```

Maybe you can see how using these in conjunction could be redundant at best, and gobble up memory/time, at worst.

Powershell likes to be "helpful". If you give it a group and a condition that normally is used to evaluate a single object, it assumes you must have wanted to test that condition individually on each object in the group, so it usually does just that, even in situations where it wouldn't make logical sense to us, and it says nothing of it. That was one of the hardest things for me to get used to, and it still trips me up from time to time